# Android ListView style

Tags: android, listview, css-selectors

I have a question about list views. I hope someone knows the solution, because I have been trying to solve this problem all weekend.

I have a custom list view in which every row have a custom `.xml` (`item_row.xml`) with a set color background for the row item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="70dip"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@drawable/list_bg">
```

The problem is that when I try to make a selector for the list. I want two things:

- When the item is focused,  the typical orange rectangle should appear over it,
- and the same When the item is pressed.

I have proved with a selector and a custom style but all I get is or the selector doesn't appear or the selector covering the item so I can't see it.

If anyone could help me with finding the right code I would be very grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an attribute to your `ListView` tag.

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_bg"
```

Now you can create your own style for your background using the XML file as drawable. For more information, check out the API Demos app, drawables section.

Answer (score 3):

There is a special parameter for listview selected backgronud, i.e. android:listSelector. Setting this parameter to the background resource will solve your problem.