# How to use Selector when click a item in list

Tags: android, download, selector, listactivity

I occur a problem when develop a application on android.

There have two image which can be download from server in a list item, it will show one image and will show another image when user select or click this item .
if I try to download another image from server when user click it,the user will never have time to see it, for this time is shorter than download image form server,
so i want to download two of them,and when I click it again,the app can invoke another image from local.

but I do not know how to invoke this image ?

Any suggestion will be appreciate.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put selector images on the drawable resource folder. if you download it from server then it will reduce your apps performance. check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398380/android-listview-style/2399470#2399470) of mine.

Comment: sorry,can you give me more detail how to put images on drawable resource folder during the runtime?

Comment: i suggest about statically. on runtime, it reduces your app performance.