# PreferencesActivity - customize style of checbkoxes, radio buttons etc

Tags: android, checkbox, radio-button, preferences, preferencescreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change icons of checked and unchecked for Checkbox for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192173/change-icons-of-checked-and-unchecked-for-checkbox-for-android)
>   [customize check box preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569412/customize-check-box-preference)

Is there any way to customize style of elements in `PreferencesActivity`?

I was only able to change color text, background etc.

I want to also change the check mark and radio button style in `CheckBoxPreference` and so on.

I'm interesting in API8 or greater.

Thanks for your help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="vibrate"
        android:summary="summary"
        android:title="Some title"
        android:widgetLayout="@layout/custom_checkbox" />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="autorotate"
        android:summary="summary"
        android:title="auto rotate" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand what you are saying now. I thought you were just using normal `CheckBox` inside your `View`. You are using `CheckBoxPreference` and the other `Preference` `Views`.

Ok, well the concept is very similar.

You need to define a custom widget layout. Do this in your `res/layout` directory and call it **`custom_checkbox.xml`**. We can use the `CheckBox` as an example.

Define how you would like the `CheckBoxPreference` to look with the custom widget layout you create in the `res/layout` directory by using a `CheckBox`. For instance:

```
<CheckBox
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+android:id/customCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/android_button"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false" />
```

You can replace `android:button` with any `drawable` that you have found or designed.

Now you need to define your `CheckBoxPreference` and setting its `android:widgetLayout` to the custom `CheckBox` you just defined in `res/layout`. For example:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="@string/Drop_Option"
    android:title="Close after call drop"
    android:widgetLayout="@layout/custom_checkbox" />
```

If you are not using `xml` for defining your `layout` you can do it in code like this:

```
    CheckBoxPreference checkBoxPreference = new CheckBoxPreference(this);
    checkBoxPreference.setWidgetLayoutResource(R.layout.custom_checkbox);
```

[Resources found that were similar to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569412/customize-check-box-preference)

**Konstantin Burov**

---

**Related links to extended questions from comments:**

> Also, how to change style of list item?

[android-listview-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398380/android-listview-style)

> Also, I would like to add some paddings to list items.

[spacing-between-listview-items-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984313/spacing-between-listview-items-android)

Comment: It not the case. I need to add those to CheckBoxPreference, ListPreference and so on. You way is okay, but it doesn't work with those. There is no background attribute.

Comment: I miss understood your question. Please read my edit. I understand what you said now. Once you can confirm this answer is correct, i will remove the previous answer.

Comment: Okay, this seems promising :) I couldn't find link between xml for CheckBoxPreferences and custom_checkbox.xml -> android:widgetLayout="@layout/custom_checkbox". I will test it after work.

Comment: Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Yes it is working but I got another problem. Now, not whole entry (with name, summary etc) is clickable, but only checkbox image :/ Also, how to change style of list item? I want to have window background (image) and white backgrounds for list items. Is there any chance to do it? Also, I would like to add so paddings to list items. I'm not sure if it is even possible. Maybe override whole PreferencesActivity?

Comment: Ok, i added links in my answer to your extended questions. If that does not satisfy your extended questions, feel free to post those questions as new questions here on SO. good luck!

Comment: Once again I'm not too clear. I don't want to change style of ListView, by "list item" I meant items of PreferencesActivity (poor naming ;)). I added sample code to explain. I want to change look of CheckBoxPreference - after executing this activity it looks like list. When I add two CheckBoxPreference there will be two "items". Do you get it? :) And now I want to change style of those. I list I want to change background [link](http://bit.ly/OJJIqh) Red arrow points to filed I meant as a "item" and I need to make background white (plus paddings, but first background).

Comment: No, i am sorry, i do not understand what you mean. You may want to start another question. And include pictures of what you are wanting compared to what you are actually seeing. That will help others understand easier.

Comment: That is probably the best option. Thanks for you help!